# Instagram on iOS8

Tags: ios, instagram, alamofire, instagram-api, swifty-json

I want to display my instagram on iOS app. I'm using Alamofire and Swifty libraries for JSON with this tutorial http://myxcode.net/2015/07/12/getting-data-from-instagram-account/

However I'm getting error in this line:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseJSON { (request, response, json, error) in
```

saying "Void expects 1 argument but 4 were used in closure body".

But if I use

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url)
     .responseJSON { response in
         print(response)
     }
```

It prints the result correctly.

If i use

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url)
        .responseJSON { response in
            let data = response["data"].arrayValue as [JSON]?
```

that I got from https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire
I get error "Type 'Response' has no subscript members"

How can I use this?

Comment: You can use `response.data` to get the raw data returned by the server. And you can use `JSON(data: data)` to get the JSON object. Or you can use `response.result.value`. It will be a `[String: AnyObject]` type JSON already.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned on the Almofire GitHub page you have to use following if you want to get 4 parameters directly

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
         .response { request, response, data, error in
             print(request)
             print(response)
             print(data)
             print(error)
          }
```

You can't use 4 parameters with the `responseJSON` as it only has one parameter as you have written in the example

but you can get 4 value from the response like this

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
         .responseJSON { response in
             print(response.request)  // original URL request
             print(response.response) // URL response
             print(response.data)     // server data
             print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

             if let JSON = response.result.value {
                 print("JSON: \(JSON)")
             }
         }
```

You can get everything from the response object